# Disable Parent Window after open.window

Tags: javascript, popup, onclick, window, parent

I want to link to an amazon music preview player as an popup from my site. I have this code:

```
<a href="http://www.amazon.de/gp/recsradio/radio/B000002OK3/" target="_blank" onclick="window.open(this.href,'popper','scrollbars=1,width=900,height=600'); return false;" onkeypress="window.open(this.href,'popper','scrollbars=1,width=900,height=600'); return false;">Link</a>
```

My Problem is, when I click on the Album Cover in the Amazon Popup, my parent site with the link refreshs with the target Amazon url. When I open the Popup URL by typing the url in the adressbar and then click on the cover, a new window is opend with the target url (this is what I want to force).

Is it possible to don't pass the parent relation with the link popup window?

Comment: For some reason `return false;` is not canceling the click event. It should. Make a proper function call out of it? I actually wrote about this, cause I see this pop up often: http://fritsvancampen.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/how-to-cancel-events-in-javascript/

Comment: I am not sure if i got you right. My page with the link does not change when I click on the amazon link (was it this what you mean with not canceling the click event?). It is just the JS link (CD Cover) on the linked amazon page, which force to open the target in the parent window (my page). I want to prevent my page count as parent window for this link on amazon site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my Problem using something like this:

Open a local popup.php from my site with JS while passing amazonurl as var.

```
<a onkeypress="window.open(this.href,'popup','scrollbars=1,width=900,height=600'); return false;" onclick="window.open(this.href,'popper','scrollbars=1,width=900,height=600'); return false;" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://domain.com/popup.php?amazonurl=http://[...]">Link</a>
```

In popup.php I use

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
window.opener = null; window.location.href = "<?php echo $_GET['amazonurl']; ?>;</script>
```

To make windpw.opener = null and then refresh the popup with the amazon URL.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using "popper" as the identifier for both instances of winow.open. The main one that opens the initial popup should be different from the one that is inside the popup itself, unless you want it to change the popup that is already open (in which case, the window.open in the onclick attribute is essentially unnecessary).

What I mean is by this:
Say you are launching the original popup with the code in question like this:

```
<a href="popup.html" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'popper'); return false;">Popup</a>
```

And the popup with the code in question is this  (popup.html):

```
<a href="http://www.amazon.de/gp/recsradio/radio/B000002OK3/" target="_blank" onclick="window.open(this.href,'popper','scrollbars=1,width=900,height=600'); return false;" onkeypress="window.open(this.href,'popper','scrollbars=1,width=900,height=600'); return false;">Link</a>
```

You need to make sure the original popup identifier is different from the one in the popup. So, the original popup should be something like:

```
<a href="popup.html" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'original-popper'); return false;">Popup</a>
```

Comment: Can You explain this a bit further? I tried to name the onclick "popper" and the onkeypress "popup", but this doesn't help. If there is a more proper way to link the player and break the parent/child relation, let me know.

Comment: Now I got what you mean. The popup target I link is not my site, it is amazon. I neither want to change the target amazon popup, nor my parent window. I use JS Popup to have a nice fitting window to the music preview player, but if I link with a plain html link, I have the same issue. The link on amazon popup is forced to open in parent window, that is what I would like to prevent.

Comment: You said the parent window is also a popup, correct? Or at least, the window that has the code in question is already a popup, right? Make sure the code you're using to launch the popup that contains this code doesn't also use "popper" to identify the window. I'll clarify in my post, give me a second to edit it.

Comment: No, parent window is no popup. On MySite(A), I have a link to Amazon(B) [ for example http://www.amazon.de/gp/recsradio/radio/B000002OK3/ ]. When I click the link on MySite(A) I open Amazon(B) in a new Window or Popup. Until here it is fine. When I now click in the CD Cover in the new Amazon(B) Window, the target opens in MySite(A) because MySite(A) is somehow the parent Window and that is what I want to prevent.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. The Amazon popup has a link that is opening in the parent window, correct? Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way for you to change this without modifying the DOM of the Amazon page or creating some hacky work-around. The album cover link on the Amazon page is calling `amz_js_RefreshOriginalWindow('http://www.amazon.de/Reservoir-Dogs-Ost-Various/dp/B000002OK3/ref=pd_krex_fa_img'); return false;`. Perhaps if you do `window.opener = window; window.parent = window;` in  your popup, it might stop the Amazon page from updating the original window.

Comment: Thanks Gawdl3y for your help. I only use one Popup, not a second one. I finally solved the my Problem by opening a local file as popup and refreshing it with the amazon url.